# How to remove address bar from sales force login page.I am using sales force hybrid sdk?

Tags: cordova, salesforce, hybrid-mobile-app

Can i remove the address bar from the login page on sales force hybrid sdk? that is using cordova system browser.Please suggest me if i can change it to inapp browser.